# Node module for DRY CRUD endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, crud

As a learning project I recently started writing a node module to generate / handle the creation of CRUD endpoints in a DRY way.

The problem I was initially wanting to solve was that in my generator-angular-fullstack project I had several basic CRUD endpoints that all had identical controllers (e.g. [this](https://github.com/paulparton/feedboss/blob/master/server/api/source/source.controller.js)).

My idea was a module that would generate those CRUD methods for different database types, something like:

```
var dryCrud = new DryCrud({
    type: 'mongoose',
    collection: MyMongooseCollection
});

app.get('/', dryCrud.read);
app.get('/:', dryCrud.read({
    query: {'_id':'^id'}   // <--  the ^ = req.params.
}));
```

Then I had the idea of generating a full set of basic CRUD endpoints:

```
dryCrud.init('routePrefix', app);
```

The .init creates a create, read, read/:id, update/:id and delete endpoint using the supplied express app (or router) with each route prefixed by the `'routePrefix'`, connecting with the database specified in the `dryCrud` creation.

I have created a pretty basic module, and two database adaptors (Mongo native and Mongoose) [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/crudbrella).

I feel like I have been staring at this in isolation for a while, and I would love to know if anyone else thinks a module like this would be useful. Is it worth developing it further? I would also welcome any feedback on my code / structure.

### The Crudbrella module

#### index.js

```
var _ = require('lodash'),
    utils = require("./lib/utils-prototype"),
    Crudbrella;

Crudbrella = function(config){

    //Check for required config
    if(!config.collection || !config.type){

        //Raise an error here...
        console.error("dryCrud error: you must provide a database object and type");
        process.exit(e.code);

        return false;

    }

    //Constructor of crudbrella object being returned to the user
    var newCrud = function(){
        this.collection = config.collection;
        this.type = config.type;
    };

    //Include core functionality and utility methods
    _.extend(newCrud.prototype, utils);

    //If the type provided is a string
    if (typeof config.type == 'string' || config.type instanceof String){

        //attempt to load and use the module
        try {

            var adaptorModule = require(config.type);

        } catch(e) {

            console.error("Adaptor " + config.typre + " is not found");
            process.exit(e.code);

        }

    //If the type provided is a module
    }else{

        adaptorModule = config.type;

    }

    //use the module
    _.extend(newCrud.prototype, adaptorModule);

    return new newCrud();

};

module.exports = Crudbrella;
```

#### ./libs/utils-prototype.js

```
var _  = require('lodash');

module.exports = {

    //Default success callback (can be replaced at runtime)
    successCallback: function(res, result){

        if(!result) { return res.send(404, ""); }

        res.send(result);

    },

    //Default error callback (can be replaced at runtime)
    errorCallback: function(res, error){

        res.send(500, error);

    },

    //Standard db callback
    dbCallback: function(data){

        //If there is an error
        if(data.err && data.err !== null){

            //Use a user defined or default error callback
            return data.onError(data.res, data.err || "empty");

        }

        if(data.req.method == 'DELETE'){
            data.result = true;
        }

        //Use a user defined or default success callback
        return data.onSuccess(data.res, data.result);

    },
    init: function(root, app){

        root = root.replace(/\/$/, "");

        app.get(root + '/', this.read());
        app.get(root + '/:id', this.read({query:{_id:'^id'}}));
        app.post(root + '/', this.create());
        app.put(root + '/:id', this.update());
        app.delete(root + '/:id', this.delete());

    },
    utils: {
        //Depopulate populated mongoose documents (move this to the mongoose adaptor)
        depopulate: function (model, doc){

            //loop through each item in the model
            _.each(model.schema.tree, function(item, key){

                var schemaDetails = JSON.stringify(item) || "";

                //If the item has a 'ref' property
                if (schemaDetails.indexOf('ref') !== -1){

                    //For that item in the current document
                    doc[key] = _.map(doc[key], function(value){

                        return value._id;

                    });

                }

            });

        }

    }
};
```

### The mongoose adaptor

```
var _  = require('lodash');

module.exports =  {

    //Create a new record
    create: function (options){

        return function(req, res){

            //If no options are provided default to an empty object
            options = options || {};

            this.collection.create(req.body, function(err, result) {

                //Pass results and req/res to the dbCallback
                this.dbCallback({
                    req: req, 
                    res: res, 
                    err: err, 
                    result: result,
                    onSuccess:options.onSuccess || this.successCallback,
                    onError:options.onError || this.errorCallback
                });

            }.bind(this));

        }.bind(this);

    },

    //Read an existing record / records
    read: function(options){

        return function (req, res){

            //If no options are provided default to an empty object
            options = options || {};
            options.query = options.query || {};

            //Create a local copy of the query definition to be parsed
            var query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options.query)) || {};

            //Loop through every object in query
            _.each(query, function(item, key){

                //If the value starts with a ^ use the item value as a key for req.params
                if(item[0] === "^"){
                    query[key] = req.params[item.replace("^","")];
                }

            });

            //Find using optional query or find all
            this.collection.find(query || {})

                //Process options populate string / object or default to empty string
                .populate(options.populate || '')

                //Execute the query
                .exec(function(err, items){

                    if(items.length === 1){
                        items = items[0];
                    }

                    //Pass results and req/res to the dbCallback
                    this.dbCallback({
                        req: req, 
                        res: res, 
                        err: err, 
                        result: items,
                        onSuccess:options.onSuccess || this.successCallback,
                        onError:options.onError || this.errorCallback
                    });

                }.bind(this)

            );

        }.bind(this);
    },

    //Update a record
    update: function(options){

        return function(req, res){

            //If no options are provided default to an empty object
            options = options || {};

            //If the id has been included in the body, remove it
            var x = req.body._id; 
            delete req.body._id;

            //Check if the body contains any populated fields and depopulate them
            this.utils.depopulate(this.collection, req.body);

            //Use crudbrella read to find the document to be updated
            this.read({

                query: {_id: x},

                //custom success handler to complete update, use default for errors
                onSuccess: function(innerRes, result){

                    var updated = _.extend(result, req.body);

                    updated.save(function (err, actualResult) {

                        //Pass results and req/res to the dbCallback
                        this.dbCallback({
                            req: req, 
                            res: res, 
                            err: err, 
                            result: actualResult,
                            onSuccess:options.onSuccess || this.successCallback,
                            onError:options.onError || this.errorCallback
                        });

                    }.bind(this));

                }.bind(this)

            })(req, res);

        }.bind(this);

    },

    //Delete a record
    delete: function(options){

        return function(req, res){

            //If no options are provided default to an empty object
            options = options || {};

            //If the id has been included in the body, remove it
            if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }

            //Check if the body contains any populated fields and depopulate them
            this.utils.depopulate(this.collection, req.body);

            //Use dryCrud.read to find the document to be deleted
            this.collection.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, result){

                //Pass results and req/res to the dbCallback
                this.dbCallback({
                    req: req, 
                    res: res, 
                    err: err, 
                    result: "",
                    onSuccess:options.onSuccess || this.successCallback,
                    onError:options.onError || this.errorCallback
                });

            }.bind(this));

        }.bind(this);

    }

};
```

### The native mongo adaptor

```
var _  = require('lodash'),
        ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

module.exports =  {

    //Create a new record
    create: function (options){

        return function(req, res){

            //If no options are provided default to an empty object
            options = options || {};

            //Save the object into the collection
            this.collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result) {

                //Pass results and req/res to the dbCallback
                this.dbCallback({
                    req: req, 
                    res: res, 
                    err: err, 
                    result: result,
                    onSuccess:options.onSuccess || this.successCallback,
                    onError:options.onError || this.errorCallback
                });

            }.bind(this));

        }.bind(this);

    },
    //Check if a given string is a valid mongo ObjectId
    validId: function(id){

        checkForHexRegExp = /^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i;

        if (id.match(checkForHexRegExp)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    },
    //Read an existing record / records
    read: function(options){

        return function (req, res){

            //If no options are provided default to an empty object
            options = options || {};

            //If no query has been provided default to an empty object
            options.query = options.query || {};

            //Create a local copy of the query definition to be parsed
            var query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options.query)) || {};

            //Loop through every object in query
            _.each(query, function(item, key){

                //If the value starts with a ^ use the item value as a key for req.params
                if(item[0] === "^"){

                    if(this.validId(req.params[item.replace("^","")])){ 

                        query[key] = ObjectId(req.params[item.replace("^","")]);

                    }else{

                        query[key] = req.params[item.replace("^","")];  

                    }

                }

            }.bind(this));

            //Find using optional query or find all
            this.collection.find(query || {}).toArray(function(err, items){

                if(items.length === 1){
                    items = items[0];
                }

                //Pass results and req/res to the dbCallback
                this.dbCallback({
                    req: req, 
                    res: res, 
                    err: err, 
                    result: items,
                    onSuccess:options.onSuccess || this.successCallback,
                    onError:options.onError || this.errorCallback
                });

            }.bind(this));

        }.bind(this);

    },

    //Update a record
    update: function(options){

        return function(req, res){

            var requestId;

            //If no options are provided default to an empty object
            options = options || {};

            //If the id has been included in the body, remove it
            requestId = ObjectId(req.params.id); 
            delete req.body._id;

            //Check if the body contains any populated fields and depopulate them
            this.collection.update({'_id': requestId},{$set: req.body}, function(err, result){

                if(!err){
                    result = req.body;
                }

                this.dbCallback({
                    req: req, 
                    res: res, 
                    err: err, 
                    result: result,
                    onSuccess:options.onSuccess || this.successCallback,
                    onError:options.onError || this.errorCallback
                });

            }.bind(this));

        }.bind(this);

    },

    //Delete a record
    delete: function(options){

        return function(req, res){

            //If no options are provided default to an empty object
            options = options || {};

            //If the id has been included in the body, remove it
            if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }

            //Use dryCrud.read to find the document to be deleted
            this.collection.remove({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err, result){

                //Pass results and req/res to the dbCallback
                this.dbCallback({
                    req: req, 
                    res: res, 
                    err: err, 
                    result: "",
                    onSuccess:options.onSuccess || this.successCallback,
                    onError:options.onError || this.errorCallback
                });

            }.bind(this));

        }.bind(this);

    }

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, I think it could be interesting as a stand-alone module. There's can be a lot of repetitive boilerplate involved in connecting a REST api to a CRUD backend, reducing that is certainly worth a module, in my opinion.

Now to dive into the code...

### index.js

> ```
> if(!config.collection || !config.type){
>    //Raise an error here...
>    console.error("dryCrud error: you must provide a database object and type");
>    process.exit(e.code);
>    return false;
>  }
> ```

It makes more sense to me to throw an exception here than to exit the process.

> ```
> catch(e) {
>        console.error("Adaptor " + config.typre + " is not found");
>        process.exit(e.code);
> }
> ```

- `typre` strikes me as a typo.
- Again, I would prefer an throwing an exception (e.g. `e`) over `process.exit`.

### utils-prototype.js

#### successCallback

> ```
> if(!result) { return res.send(404, ""); }
> ```

Are you positive you want to return 404 on falsy values? Also, as far as I can tell this is Express 3.x syntax, the two-argument version of send is not mentioned in the Express 4.x api documentation. Using `res.status(404).send("Not Found")` is compatible with either version.

#### errorCallback

Passing the error message directly to the user may be convenient during development, but it is generally considered insecure. Sending `error` to the user doesn't strike me as a good default.

#### dbCallback

> ```
>    //If there is an error
>    if(data.err && data.err !== null){
>        //Use a user defined or default error callback
>        return data.onError(data.res, data.err || "empty");
>    }
> ```

- the check in the if condition is redundant, as `null` is falsy.
- the `|| "empty"` is redundant as `data.err` is always truthy in this path.

> ```
> if(data.req.method == 'DELETE'){
>         data.result = true;
> }
> ```

I did not expect to find this here at all. It seems to be working around the fact that there is no meaningful response body to send back for a delete request, but the `result` argument to `onSuccess` mustn't be falsy, or you'll get a 404. What I would in fact expect in this case is a 204 (No Content) response. To achieve this, you probably need different default success handlers for different request types.

#### utils.depopulate

This function definitely belongs in the mongoose adapter as the comment already states.

> ```
> var schemaDetails = JSON.stringify(item) || "";
>            //If the item has a 'ref' property
>            if (schemaDetails.indexOf('ref') !== -1){
> ```

I sincerely doubt that this is what you want to do. What if the item has a `prefered` or `prefix` property (those also contain `ref`)? The fact that you're  calling `JSON.stringify` here suggests to me that `item` actually has a richer structure and you might actually test if `item.ref !== undefined` or something like that (I am not familiar enough with mongoose to know the metadata structure you are traversing here).

### The adapters

I'll cover both adapters in one go. The interaction with mongo / mongoose is sufficiently similar.

> ```
> //Create a local copy of the query definition to be parsed
> var query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options.query)) || {};
> ```

Shouldn't you use something like `_.clone` or `_.cloneDeep` for this?

> ```
> if(items.length === 1){
>     items = items[0];
> }
> ```

It seems like this is again working around the limitations in your default success handler. When I query a single object using the `get('/:id')` route, I expect a single object in the response. But when I query a route that can return multiple objects, like `get('/')`, I expect to always get an array back, even when there happens to be just one element in the array. Again, I think this logic should be replaced by having a different success callback for different routes.

The `update` and `delete` methods are missing any way to prevent concurrent modifications. It might be a little tricky to prevent this as it depends on information embedded in the data (like a modification timestamp or version field). From a usability perspective, preventing users from overwriting or removing data they haven't even seen is pretty important though, if you ask me.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You passed through the First Post Review with flying colors!